# Add index on column or not?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255),
`my_number` int(10) unsigned default NULL
);
```

There are a hundreds of thousands of items, and I usually order them by 'my_number'.

Will adding an index on 'my_number' increase performance on queries when I order by this field?

I use MySQL, the table is InnoDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know the answer but it doesn't matter. What you should do in *all* cases of potential database optimisation is to add the index and *test* it. And, by that, I mean test all of your affected queries, inserts and updates to ensure you have a performance boost that outdoes any loss of performance elsewhere.

You shouldn't trust my knowledge or anyone else's if the alternative is concrete data that you can gather yourself. *Measure, don't guess!*

The answer is, by the way: "it should, unless your DBMS is truly brain-dead". Generally, adding indexes will increase the speed of selects but slow down inserts and updates. But I *mean* "generally" - it's not always the case. A good DBA continuously examines the performance of the DBMS and tunes it where necessary. Databases are not set-and-forget objects, they need to be cared for and nurtured :-)

Comment: Well I tested, and adding an index increased performance dramatically.

That makes you right both on testing and indexing :-)